# TypeError: DataFrame.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index_col'

Tags: python, pandas

I can't understand the error, I've tried several things

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame("tratamiento_datos.csv", index_col = 0)
.
.
.
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data Science for Scratch\02_pipelines.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame("tratamiento_datos.csv", index_col = 0)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: DataFrame.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index_col'
```

Thank you for helping those of us who are learning

Comment: The error you are encountering is clearly stated in the message, and you can fix it simply by checking [documentation of the function you used](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).  However, you are asking a question even though you need a learning assistant. **SO is not learning assistant.** It is better to ask questions about problems that arise during your studies in your lecture class, and to use Google search or chatgpt for additional help.

Comment: Why do you think that the argument `index_col` should be accepted?

Comment: I think you want `pd.read_csv("tratamiento_datos.csv", index_col = 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message provides everything you need to determine what's wrong, but I understand why it may be confusing if you're just starting out.

The error is that you're not using the correct function to read a csv. You're using the `pandas.DataFrame()` constructor function, which expects you to pass it the actual data you want in the dataframe. The string containing the path to the file with your data isn't the actual data itself; it's just a string representation of the location where the data can be found.

I imagine what's most confusing is what this `DataFrame.__init__()` thing is. That's a special function that's called when you create any python object. When your code runs `pd.DataFrame('tratamiento_datos.csv', index_col=0)`, it's actually calling the function `DataFrame.__init__('tratamiento_datos.csv', index_col=0)`.

> TypeError: DataFrame.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index_col'

This error message is telling you that you've passed an unexpected argument, `index_col`, to the `DataFrame.__init__()` function.

Next time something like this happens, you can use the special python function `help()` and call help on the class you're getting an error from; in this case, you'd write `help(pd.DataFrame)`, and you'd see documentation around how to use this class and what arguments it takes.

On to the solution: Pandas comes with functions designed to retrieve data from various different sources. One of these functions is `pandas.read_csv()`, which is the proper way to read a csv into a DataFrame and does accept the `index_col` argument. So, what you want is:

```
df = pd.read_csv("tratamiento_datos.csv", index_col=0)
```

One of the most important steps in becoming a better coder is to not be intimidated by error messages and really take the time to read and understand them; they often include everything you need to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I was following a tutorial and it didn't show errors, which is why I got confused. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The index_col parameter should be used with pd.read_csv function, not pd.DataFrame. Use pd.read_csv to read the CSV file with the index column specified:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("tratamiento_datos.csv", index_col=0) # Read the CSV file
```

This will properly read your CSV file into a DataFrame